# Creating a CLR User Control

Tags: winforms, controls, c++-cli, clr

Under Visual Studio 2019, I would like to create a user control in C++/CLI.
I didn't succed to compil a dll.

What I did :

1. Create a new empty CLR Project (because I don't have the option to create directly a user control project)
2. Menu Project -> Properties -> Link editor -> System -> syb system -> Windows
3. Panel Solution explorer -> Right clic on Header files -> Add -> new element -> CLR -> user control CLR
4. I compil the project and restart Visual Studio (in order to access my component designer overwise the designer gives me an error)
5. I add some graphical elements on my control (buttons, labels, etc) and I compil
6. I try to find the dll in the release folder but I only find a *.dll.metagen and no dll

I tried to change : Menu Project -> Properties -> General -> configuration type -> dynamic library (.dll)
 but it does nothing better

Thanks for your help

Comment: C++ is not the same language as C++/CLI there is no C++/CLR. There is CLR.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution :
At start, when creating a new project, choose : "CLR Class Library" as type of project
next You can do : Right click on "header files" -> add -> new element" -> "-> CLR -> user control CLR".
It compile and create a dll that contain a user control that can be imported in a windows form